# Any point to use greenthreads if you have a single blocking function

Tags: python, gevent, eventlet, green-threads

Green threads in Python have cooperative multitasking to finish the job. Should they be used for the following scenario because they won't yield/pass control to other threads for it.

Scenario:

The blocking function has just one command: a long running SSH to another machine. So even if you have multiple green threads its also a possibility that multiple SSH connections don't even open,as the first thread doesn't yield control to the next one for starting a connection.

There will be an installation going on through that SSH on the machine

Comment: It depends. Can you chunk your I/O over the SSH connection? Is it waiting for a response? Can you describe in more detail your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Running SSH using `paramiko` or other Python library is socket IO, using `subprocess` is also file descriptor IO, in both cases it will yield control to other threads.

You need to use `eventlet.monkey_patch` or `eventlet.green.subprocess` to make this SSH yield control.

You do not need any green/OS threads in a simple program like this:

```
import os
os.system('ssh host command')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends if your blocking function can use a green (non blocking) ssh call. There is a 'green' library which is also cabale of ssh https://pypi.python.org/pypi/telnetsrv/0.4